# Why does Jamie specifically narrate these lines in the opening scenes?

Tags: plot-explanation, 20th-century-women

In **[20th Century Women](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4385888/)**, why does Jamie specifically mention these lines in the opening scenes?

> Jamie: I saw the president fall down the stairs...and I threw up on
>   the carpet

"**President fall down the stairs**", this segment is happening on TV which he is watching.

And "**I threw up on the carpet**", he is shown cleaning the carpet.

[image]

Comment: He simply recounts things he remembers, and for some reason those two events were in there. Kids are like that. Also, that's not him cleaning it.